# DC/DC Converter strange output

Tags: dc, converter

I am using a [DCP010505DBP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dcp010505db.pdf) with this configuration

[image: schematic]

I supply it with 5V and I obtaining:

- 10V between the pins 6 and 5
- -10V between the pins 7 and 5

I am using a fixed 5V output of my power supply and I am using an multimeter between pins 6 and 5 (+Vout) and 7 and 5 (-Vout).  The schematic I am using is on the datasheet http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=DCP010505B&fileType=pdf

What am I doing wrong? If I take a look at the datasheet I should have 5 and -5V at the outputs.

Comment: First of all you should provide a proper schematic and not a doodle. Then you should note the input voltage ratings, it is not liking 30V ...

Comment: Would you tell us *exactly* - and I mean *exactly* how you are measuring the voltages please?

Comment: Many such converters require a minimum load

Comment: @PlasmaHH to be fair, it is clear he is using the 5V fixed output of the supply.

Comment: @DiBosco: It seems to be showing 30V ...

Comment: @PlasmaHH, yes, but those PSUs have three sets of outputs. One of which is a fixed 5V output and that's what he's connected up to. If you maximise the picture it's even clearer.

Comment: @DiBosco: ah, so we are supposed to figure out what PSU this is, read its manual and then have a look at that? fair enough, obviously its our duty to gather together all the right information and discard the red herrings...

Comment: @PlasmaHH No, just look at the photo and see the fact the wires come out of a pair of terminals clearly marked 5V. :)

Comment: @DiBosco: not clearly on my phone, and there is a clear 30V displayed, but surely it was obvious that one knows that this 30V isn't the real one and one has to download the image and zoom into it to look around what was meant really.

Comment: I am using a fixed 5V output of my power supply and I am using an multimeter between pins 6 and 5 (+Vout) and 7 and 5 (-Vout).  The schematic I am using is on the datasheet http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=DCP010505B&fileType=pdf

Comment: @PlasmaHH OK, we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Fran, ok, well, following Scott's observation, if you put a load on each output, say 470R, which should take about 10mA from the unit, how do the output voltages look then?

Comment: Thanks so much, With a load of 470ohm I obtain 5 and -5V!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an **unregulated** isolated supply.

If you have a look at the datasheet they show load and line regulation only starting at 10% load.

If you have no load present (a multimeter poses no load), unregulated isolated supplies tend to increase the voltage. Depending on the design the increase can be quite substantial.

So to measure the voltage, you should present a minimal load. How little is enough depends on the supply. As the datasheet starts at 10%, that might be a good point, but maybe 5% would be enough already.

Note though, that even regulated supplies might need a minimal load for the regulation to function, so it's not necessarily different with no load present.